# Windows search override

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I know there are many alternatives to windows search. But are there any that can be used by using the search bar in the Start menu?

I can't justify using alternative software if it's less accessible than the default.

Can it be done?

Comment: Questions searching for product recommendations or lists of things are off-topic here because they go out of date quickly. You could ask how to register such a search engine, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no (at least no way that doesn't involve extensive hacking on the registry) way to modify the search bar in the windows start menu. HOWEVER, there are some nice nearly-equivalent methods to launch other search programs. As SuperUser doesn't really endorse software I won't list services apart from one as an example.

Launchy - http://www.launchy.net/ - is launched by pressing Alt+Spacebar (by default) and works much like the OSX finder search. You can configure what and where you want it to index and make searchable. There are a few programs like this which would suit your needs.

I think the overall answer to your question is 'no' but there are alternatives that are as or more accessible than the windows search, in my mind at least :)

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, alternatives to Windows search are usually better. As stated above, most alternatives are not part of the start menu. if you use [Lookeen](https://lookeen.com), the search bar is launched by double tapping Ctrl. (Much like Google dektop was)
Lookeen is also fully integrated into Outlook. The search bar appears natively in Outlook.
Hope that helps,
-Eric
(Full disclosure: I work for the company that developed Lookeen)